# Passing an instance of NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

I use [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) to work with core data.

I have a separate class called `DatabaseManager` to handle core data related tasks. I have a initializer accepting a `NSManagedObjectContext` object.

```
import CoreData
import Foundation
import MagicalRecord
import SwiftyJSON

public class DatabaseManager {

    private let context: NSManagedObjectContext!

    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.context = context
    }

    public func insertReports(data: AnyObject, success: () -> Void, failure: (error: NSError?) -> Void) {
        MagicalRecord.cleanUp()
        MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed("Records")

        let json = JSON(data)
        if let reports = json.array {
            for reportObj in reports {
                let report = Report.MR_createInContext(context) as Report
                report.id = reportObj["Id"].int
                report.type = reportObj["Type"].string!
            }
            context.MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait()
            success()
        }
    }

    private func getReport(id: Int) -> Report {
        let idFilter = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", NSNumber(integer: id))
        let fetchRequest = Report.MR_requestAllWithPredicate(idFilter, inContext: context)
        return Report.MR_executeFetchRequestAndReturnFirstObject(fetchRequest, inContext: context) as Report
    }
}
```

And I initialize the class and call it's `insertReports()` method to insert some records into core data.

```
let context = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext()
let dbManager = DatabaseManager(context: context)

getReportsFromAPI({ (data) -> Void in
    dbManager.insertReports(data, success: { () -> Void in
        println("Reports added successfully")
    }, failure: { (error) -> Void in
        println("Error inserting Reports: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    })
}, failure: { (error) -> Void in
    println("Error getting Reports from API: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
})
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I get the following output in the console.

```
2015-03-05 00:39:39.412 Reports[7123:967179] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setDefaultContext:](0x104396400) Set Default Context: (null)
2015-03-05 00:39:39.412 Reports[7123:967179] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setRootSavingContext:](0x104396400) Set Root Saving Context: (null)
2015-03-05 00:39:39.583 Reports[7123:967179] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator:](0x104396400) -> Created Context UNNAMED
2015-03-05 00:39:39.584 Reports[7123:967179] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setRootSavingContext:](0x104396400) Set Root Saving Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7f81b04c6b00>
2015-03-05 00:39:39.584 Reports[7123:967179] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_newMainQueueContext](0x104396400) Created Main Queue Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7f81b04c75a0>
2015-03-05 00:39:39.584 Reports[7123:967179] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setDefaultContext:](0x104396400) Set Default Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7f81b04c75a0>
2015-03-05 00:39:40.434 Reports[7123:967179] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setDefaultContext:](0x104396400) Set Default Context: (null)
2015-03-05 00:39:40.434 Reports[7123:967179] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setRootSavingContext:](0x104396400) Set Root Saving Context: (null)
2015-03-05 00:39:40.435 Reports[7123:967179] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setDefaultContext:](0x104396400) Set Default Context: (null)
2015-03-05 00:39:40.435 Reports[7123:967179] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setRootSavingContext:](0x104396400) Set Root Saving Context: (null)
2015-03-05 00:39:40.443 Reports[7123:967179] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator:](0x104396400) -> Created Context UNNAMED
2015-03-05 00:39:40.443 Reports[7123:967179] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setRootSavingContext:](0x104396400) Set Root Saving Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7f81b280e5a0>
2015-03-05 00:39:40.444 Reports[7123:967179] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_newMainQueueContext](0x104396400) Created Main Queue Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7f81b04d76c0>
2015-03-05 00:39:40.444 Reports[7123:967179] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setDefaultContext:](0x104396400) Set Default Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7f81b04d76c0>
2015-03-05 00:39:40.446 Reports[7123:967179] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7f81b04c75a0) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7f81b04c75a0): *** DEFAULT ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***
2015-03-05 00:39:40.446 Reports[7123:967179] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7f81b04c75a0) → Save Parents? 1
2015-03-05 00:39:40.447 Reports[7123:967179] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7f81b04c75a0) → Save Synchronously? 1
2015-03-05 00:39:40.448 Reports[7123:967179] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7f81b04c6b00) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7f81b04c6b00): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***
2015-03-05 00:39:40.448 Reports[7123:967179] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7f81b04c6b00) → Save Parents? 1
2015-03-05 00:39:40.448 Reports[7123:967179] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7f81b04c6b00) → Save Synchronously? 1
```

After that, it just freezes. No error is thrown but the saving operation doesn't get completed either.

I replaced the places where I use the property context with `NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext()` and ran the app and the data got saved successfully.

Why can't I pass in an instance of `MR_defaultContext()` through the initializer?

Comment: You should probably setup magical record in your initialiser and not in the insert call

Comment: @DanielGalasko You're absolutely right. That was the issue. If you could post it as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielGalasko Hello again. I'm having a core data, MagicalRecord related issue once again. If you can, can you please have a look? I posted a separate [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28879198/1077789).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backtrace says it all, you are setting up too many connections to the persistent store. The MagicalRecord [documentation](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/develop/Docs/Getting-Started.md) details that you should set up your stack either in the App Delegate's `didFinishLaunching` phase, or in your case, when your DatabaseManager class is instantiated.

So the call to         `MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed("Records")` should move to your initializer (possibly safer to place this inside a dispatch_once block to prevent it from being setup more than once)

```
init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    struct Static {
        static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0
    }
    dispatch_once(&(Static.onceToken)) {
        MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed("Records")
    }
    self.context = context
}
```

As an aside, you only need to call cleanup when your app is closing, so perhaps in your App Delegate's `willTerminate`

All the best with MagicalRecord :)